# C# array issue due to indexing of int

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I am fairly new to this and trying to learn. I am struggling trying to make a loop to find the max value in an array. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have searched everywhere and seen several people do it the way i am but do not know what i am missing…

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] Numbs = new int[10];
        Numbs[0] = 56;
        Numbs[1] = 77;
        Numbs[2] = 23;
        Numbs[3] = 12;
        Numbs[4] = 88;
        Numbs[5] = 59;
        Numbs[6] = 97;
        Numbs[7] = 33;
        Numbs[8] = 38;
        Numbs[9] = 64;

        string[] Names = new string[10] {"John", "George", "Henry", "Larry", "Bart", "Luke", "Tim",
            "Frank", "Conor", "Joe"};

       

        FindMax(Numbs[9],9);
       
    }

    static int FindMax(int arrayNumbs, int arrayNumbsLength)
    {
        int Greatest = -1;

        for (int Count = 0; Count <= arrayNumbsLength; Count++)
            if (arrayNumbs[Count] > Greatest)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Count);
                Greatest = arrayNumbs;
                Console.WriteLine(Greatest); 
            }
            return Greatest;
```

Comment: I assume this is a typo. Your first parameter of `FindMax` is `int arrayNums`, which is an _integer_. I assume you meant `int[] arrayNums`?

Comment: In addition, arrays in C# have a `.Length` property, so you don't need a separate parameter for an array's length.

Comment: this `FindMax(Numbs[9],9);` will only pass a single number the index no 9 (64)..

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a `List<int>()`?

Comment: @gunr2171, I don't think it is a typo, given that the argument being passed is a specific array element rather than the array. I think that it is a logic mistake and the root of the issue.

Comment: The error is in the line `Greatest = arrayNumbs;`! It should be `Greatest = arrayNumbs[i];`... and of course you need to pass `static int FindMax(int arrayNumbs[], int arrayNumbsLength)`

Comment: I'm fairly sure that that code wouldn't even compile, which you should have told us. You need to ALWAYS tell us what actually happens. If code won't compile, provide the error message(s) and where it occurs. Then we know what we're looking for. Presumably `arrayNumbs[Count]` is an issue because `arrayNumbs` isn't an array and so can't be indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic change would be:

```
static int FindMax(int[] arrayNumbs)
{

    ...
    for (int Count = 0; Count < arrayNumbs.Length; Count++)
    ...
}
```

The rest is just fine. There are some ways to make it *better*, but I'm guessing this is a school assignment and you'll get there eventually.

Comment: Yes this is a school assignment and I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I can see few things that are issues with your code:

- Your method defines first parameter as an integer (`int arrayNumbs`), it should say `int[] arrayNumbs` since you're passing an array, not a single integer
- in your function call `FindMax(Numbs[9], 9)` you pass an integer as the first argument instead of an array (which didn't give you an error since it's how you defined the method, see above). Second argument is a lie, your array's size is 10, not 9 (remember about first element having index `[0]`)
- Inside your method you want to assign the integer to your variable, not the whole array (which would give you an error). Should say `Greatest = arrayNumbs[Count]`

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful for me on this assignment. I appreciate the time you took to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a List() instead of the array type. A list is dynamic and will expand automatically. In the example below I create the numbs list and use LINQ to get the max value.

```
var numbs = new List<int>
{
    56, 77, 23, 12, 88, 59, 97, 33, 38, 65
};

var max = numbs.Max();
```